# Removing head in Doubly linked list

Tags: java

My name is Mario and i have 1 question. Why in a Doubly linked list if i have 1 -> 2 -> 3 and i want to remove head i set this.head=removedHead.getNextNode() and after i set only previous node to null?

```
public String removeHead()
 {
     Node removedHead = this.head;    // variable for removedHead
     if(removedHead ==null)
     {
         return null;
     }
     this.head=removedHead.getNextNode(); // get next node to head
     if( this.head != null)
     {
         this.head.setPreviousNode(null); // setting the previous node ==null
     }
     if(removedHead == this.tail)
     {
         this.removeTail();
     }
     return removedHead.data;
 }
```

Comment: This is more a conceptual question than a coding question. If you want to remove 1 from the list, your head is now 2 (which is removedHead.next), but being this 2 the head now, its previous member has to be null.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
My suggestion for you is - draw it on paper—step by step.
Start with initial state  `|- 1 <=> 2 <=> 3 -|` and and you have a head pointer to 1.

Comment: but next of removedHead doesnt need to be null ?

Comment: And draw each step. Also, note how I display the `null` pointer (`-|`) and how I highlighted double-linked with (`<=>`). Draw these pointers too.

Comment: Draw `removedHead`, too.

Comment: Your removedHead reference is going to be deleted by the garbage collector, as you are returning only the data contained IN the removedHead, and not the reference itself, so you don't need to set any next pointer to null.

Comment: You're welcome!